# Change Page Size Using dropdownlist in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have searching sorting and paging demo in mvc, demo is working good, I specified default page size 5, what changes should i make to change page size dynamically using dropdownlist? portion of code :-

Controller Action:-

```
  public ActionResult Index(string searchBy,string search,int? Page,string sortBy)
    {

        ViewBag.SortNameParameter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) ? "Name desc" : "";
        ViewBag.SortGenderParameter = sortBy == "Gender" ? "Gender desc" : "Gender";

        var employees = db.Employees.AsQueryable();

        if(searchBy == "Gender")
        {
           employees =  employees.Where(x => x.EmpGender == search || search == null);
        }
        else
        {
            employees = employees.Where(x => x.EmpName.StartsWith(search) || search == null);
        }

        switch(sortBy)
        {
            case "Name desc":
                    employees = employees.OrderByDescending(x=>x.EmpName);
                    break;

            case "Gender desc":
                    employees = employees.OrderByDescending(x=>x.EmpGender);
                    break;

            //case "Gender ":
            //employees = employees.OrderByDescending(x=>x.EmpGender);
            //break;

            default:
            employees = employees.OrderByDescending(x=>x.EmpName);
            break;

        }

        return View(employees.ToPagedList(Page ?? 1, 5));

    }
```

and I added pagedlistpager at end in view as below:-

```
@Html.PagedListPager(Model, Page => Url.Action("Index", new  { Page, searchBy = Request.QueryString["searchBy"], search = Request.QueryString["search"], sortBy = Request["sortBy"] }),
new PagedListRenderOptions() { Display = PagedListDisplayMode.IfNeeded, DisplayPageCountAndCurrentLocation = true, DisplayItemSliceAndTotal = true })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Its pretty simple just send the page size as dd value in the dd change event with jquery. And finally in the controller action method subsititue that incoming parameter to the  ToPagedList() method.

For ex:

```
public ActionResult Index(string searchBy,string search,int? Page,string sortBy,int ddpagesize)
    {

        ViewBag.SortNameParameter = string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy) ? "Name desc" : "";
        ViewBag.SortGenderParameter = sortBy == "Gender" ? "Gender desc" : "Gender";

        var employees = db.Employees.AsQueryable();

        if(searchBy == "Gender")
        {
           employees =  employees.Where(x => x.EmpGender == search || search == null);
        }
        else
        {
            employees = employees.Where(x => x.EmpName.StartsWith(search) || search == null);
        }

        switch(sortBy)
        {
            case "Name desc":
                    employees = employees.OrderByDescending(x=>x.EmpName);
                    break;

            case "Gender desc":
                    employees = employees.OrderByDescending(x=>x.EmpGender);
                    break;

            //case "Gender ":
            //employees = employees.OrderByDescending(x=>x.EmpGender);
            //break;

            default:
            employees = employees.OrderByDescending(x=>x.EmpName);
            break;

        }

        return View(employees.ToPagedList(Page ?? 1, ddpagesize));

    }
```

For dropdownchange event this article will be helpful:http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/drop-down-list-selected-index-changed-event-in-mvc

Thanks

Karthik

Comment: can you plz show how to pass page size as dd value as well? m beginner in mvc i tried it but not getting result